# Sockets C - Windows

Tags: c, sockets, ftp

I'm doing an academic program and i had a problem. My program is a ftp-utp simulator with sockets on C language. He is working fine in the same dispositive, but i need to use in differente dispositives. When I use in different pc's, the "ip" is not sent to recvfrom(or not received), but in same pc's, the ip is recognized. Sorry for my bad english and i'm new with sockets. Can someone help me?

Sender:

```
char *ip = (char*) malloc(strlen(message)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(ip,message);
SOCKET winsock;
SOCKADDR_IN sock;
winsock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
sock.sin_family=AF_INET;
sock.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(IP_CLIENTE);
sock.sin_port=htons(9010);
sendto(winsock,ip,strlen(ip),0,(SOCKADDR*)&sock,sizeof(sock));
```

Receiver:

```
SOCKET winsock;
SOCKADDR_IN sock;
int size=sizeof(sock);
char message[BUFLEN];

winsock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);
sock.sin_family=AF_INET;
sock.sin_port=htons(9010);
sock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP_RAST);
bind(winsock,(SOCKADDR*)&sock,sizeof(sock));

memset(message,0,sizeof(BUFLEN));
recvfrom(winsock,message,BUFLEN,0,(SOCKADDR*)&sock,&size);
closesocket(winsock);
WSACleanup();
return message;
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve] including the definitions of `IP_CLIENTE` and `IP_RAST`

Comment: Also, you're allocating too little memory for `ip` - it cannot hold the null terminator of `message`; allocate `strlen(message) + 1` bytes.

Comment: There is a problem with your translator. The word "dispositive" does not mean what you think it does -- the word you probably want is "device".

Answer (score 0):

I found the error! I just replaced "inet_addr (IP_RAST)" with "INADDR_ANY" in Receiver and now is working fine! Thanks! And yes, not is dispositive, is device! ;)